# Defining coordinates using Vector3

Tags: software, orca, pdynamo, charmm, qmmm

I am trying to implement a tether restraint in the MM region of my QM/MM calculation using pDynamo (CHARMM/ORCA interface). I need to define the origin as a Vector3. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: @CodyAldaz It is a maximum distance tether from a fixed point. I need to know how to define/format the vector 3. pDynamo does have this capability.

Comment: @CodyAldaz From what I can see in the code, yes.

Comment: @CodyAldaz check the SoftConstraints.py file in pMolecule

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In pdynamo 3.0.9

A `vector3` can be defined by importing from `Geometry` module. For example,

`center = Vector3.Null ( )`

It looks like a vector3 is just 3 element vector. Not really sure but here is what I found in `pScientific/Symmetry/PointGroupFinder.py` file

You will need to get the center of mass however by looping over each atom in the geometry
e.g.

$X_i = \displaystyle\sum_a^{N_a} m_a x_{ia}/M $

Which could be done in python like

`np.sum([xyz[i,:]*atomic_masses[i]/M for i in range(self.natoms)],axis=0)`

However, you are going to want to use an explicit for loop and loop over the `coordinates3` of your geometry. Furthermore, you're gonna need the masses.

It looks like that's stored in `system.atoms` e.g. `atom.mass`

But that's a separate problem.

There may be a simple trick to do this but I'm not that familiar with pDynamo!